# is there a way to add html script after redirect with a particular information in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add a specific html script after a successful redirect in laravel. I tried doing this though, cant figure out how to do this.  This is my code:

```
return redirect('/edit-department' . '/' . $id)->with('status','Updated!' . <a href="#"> Return to homepage </a>);
```

how do i add this after redirecting user. Thank you

Comment: That's not the correct way to concat strings in PHP (in fact, there is no need at all to concat). Try `'Updated! <a href="#"> Return to homepage </a>'`

Comment: its appearing as a normal string. I want the ***Return to Homepage*** as a link not a string

Comment: Can you show us your template that's responsible for showing the status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `{!! !!}` tags to display the raw unescaped HTML of your status:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {!! session('status') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

This way the value doesn't get escaped with `htmlspecialchars`.

The Blade compiler compiles `{{ $var }}` to `<?php htmlspecialchars($var); ?>` whereas `{!! $var !!}` will be compiled to `<?php echo $var; ?>`.

See the docs on how to [display data in Blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data) for more information.

In your controller there's no need to concatenate the HTML as a separate string.

```
return redirect('/edit-department/'.$id)
    ->with('status', 'Updated! <a href="#"> Return to homepage</a>');
```